# Dynamic Result Redirection in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

How to redirect to dynamic URL given page which value stored in variable in Struts 2?
I am performing Dynamic Method Invocation in struts 2. When LoginCheck() method executes and returns "Error", I want to redirect to Login.jsp. And following are my methods of controller:

```
 public String LoginCheck() throws Exception {
    setrURL("Login.jsp");
    System.out.println(cmodel.Login());
    System.out.println("Page = " + rURL);
    return (cmodel.Login()) ? "LSuccess" : "Error";
}
```

And it is navigating to wrong page.

Struts.xml:

```
<struts>
<!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true"></constant>
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <interceptors>  
        <interceptor name="RegValidate" class="Interceptors.RegValidateInterceptor"></interceptor>  
    </interceptors>  
    <action name="regAction" class="Controller.ClientController">
        <interceptor-ref name="RegValidate"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="RSuccess">Login.jsp</result>
        <result name="LSuccess">Home.jsp</result>
        <result name="Error" type="redirect">${rURL}</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Comment: Which Struts version? if 2.5 or later, have you defined `getrURL` (with lower-case r) ?

Comment: @YasserZamani, Yes it is defined correctly with 'r' lower case and Struts version in 2.0.

Comment: For S2.0 try also defining `getRURL` (with upper-case R)

Comment: Thank you sir... its working... @YasserZamani

Comment: you're welcome :)

Comment: @YasserZamani, please add your suggestion in answer so that i can mark it as appropriate answer.

Comment: I would like but @roman-c tagged this as duplicate and answers are closed and disabled :(

Comment: Ohhh... it's okk... but Thank you for your valuable help... :)

Comment: You're welcome ... I flagged the question if a moderator can open it again for an answer :)